# Angular2 Redirect to route on startup

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I am making use of `@ngrx/store` and observables. I have a user reducer that sets information about a user, including a user's JWT.

A `NavigationService` is injected in to the root `AppComponent` which subscribes to the `user` model and will route based upon the presence of a user's token. A `UserService` reads local storage and will dispatch to the `user` reducer the result.

The problem is that when I try to route to the home page with `goToLogin()` I get the error below...which doesn't give much information.

I am guessing that the route components are not set up yet. Is there a way to wait for the application to load before routing? Or does the error below indicate a different issue?

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  private subscription: any;

  constructor(public router:Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.subscription = this.userService.token$.subscribe(token => {
       if (token) {
         this.goToSecretStuff();
       } else {
         this.goToLogin();
       }
    });
  }


TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at Object.implementsOnDestroy (pipe_lifecycle_reflector.ts:2)
    at Function.ChangeDetectionUtil.callPipeOnDestroy (change_detection_util.ts:209)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_CohortList_0.dehydrateDirectives (viewFactory_CohortList:91)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.dehydrate (abstract_change_detector.ts:177)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.destroyRecursive (abstract_change_detector.ts:200)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.destroyRecursive (abstract_change_detector.ts:207)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.destroyRecursive (abstract_change_detector.ts:207)
    at AppView.destroy (view.ts:159)
    at AppViewManager_.destroyViewInContainer (view_manager.ts:286)
    at ViewContainerRef_.remove (view_container_ref.ts:166)
    at ComponentRef_.dispose [as _dispose] (dynamic_component_loader.ts:283)
    at ComponentRef_.dispose (dynamic_component_loader.ts:87)
    at router_outlet.ts:108
    at e.run (zone-microtask.min.js:8)
    at e.run (ng_zone.ts:371)
    at zone-microtask.min.js:8
    at z (zone-microtask.min.js:8)
    at A (zone-microtask.min.js:8)
    at zone-microtask.min.js:8
    at zone-microtask.min.js:1
    at microtask (ng_zone.ts:410)
    at e.run (zone-microtask.min.js:8)
    at e.run (ng_zone.ts:371)
    at zone-microtask.min.js:8
    at MutationObserver.h (zone-microtask.min.js:8)
```

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I couldn't find solution after few hours, but I think I found the cause - it's the `async` pipe in the route component's template. Seams like it's `unsubscribe()` and host component's `onDestroy()` are in conflict that causes this error. If you can confirm on your code we can report a bug...

Comment: Wow, how did you discover that? Looks like your assumption is correct. I removed the `| async` from my template and it worked.

Comment: Well, apparently it's a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5169 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams like this is a known bug [#5169](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5169), [#6425](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6425), as @nathasm mentioned in comments.

Workaround is to remove `async` pipe from route component's template if/when it throws error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

#### Update:

I've been looking more into this, but couldn't find any way to avoid pipe error ;( Even tried creating my own `|asynx` pipe. Best way I found to resolve this (and with minimal changes) is to subscribe in the `constructor()` and trigger change detection at `routerOnActivate()`

```
  constructor(public store: Store<any>, private _cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // this.items$ = this.store.select('items');
    this.store.select('items')
      .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
  }
  routerOnActivate(next, prev) {
    this._cdref.markForCheck();
  }
```

In my specific case I can get rid of most of this boilerplate, since my route components extend base class that already does something `onActivate()`:

```
export class ItemListRoute extends _BaseRoute {
  public items: any;
  constructor(public store: Store<any>) {
    super(store);
    this.store.select('items')
      .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
  }
}
```